# Material UI button's padding can't be adjusted

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, styled-jsx

Regardless of what px value do I choose, nothing happens. The only times when something is altered is when I adjust either the paddingLeft or the paddingRight parameter, but here, another peculiar thing happens since if I try to set both paddings nothing happens, therefore the trick works only when setting just one sort of padding.

```
  <Button
      variant='secondary'
      sx={{
        fontSize: '0.9rem',
        fontWeight: 500,
        m: '1rem',
        px: '0.1rem',//nothing happens
        outline: 'none',
        '&:focus': {
          outline: 'none',
        },
      }}
    >
      enable notifications
    </Button>
```

Comment: if you inspect the button, you'll see that the `padding` is applied but because it's only a tiny adjustment, you can't see the `padding` visually. changing one side only will push the element a little bit in the opposite direction, thus, you are able to see the adjustment. ( _for testing purposes: try to set `px: '2rem'`, are you now able to see the padding?_ )

Comment: Indeed, if I apply a huge padding it is visible. The problem is that I would like to get rid of the default x-axis padding/shrink it, since it is way too big the default one. Even when I try to set `px: '0'` nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Material UI by default sets a min-width to a button. If you would like to get rid of the x padding and shrink it, do the following:

```js
<Button
  variant='secondary'
  sx={{
    minWidth: 0,
    maxWidth: 'fit-content',
    fontSize: '0.9rem',
    fontWeight: 500,
    m: '1rem',
    px: '0.1rem',//nothing happens
    outline: 'none',
    '&:focus': {
      outline: 'none',
    },
  }}
>
 enable notifications
</Button>
```

Comment: I've tried this and nothing changed. To get a better understanding of my code, you may have a look at my entire jsx file: https://github.com/linuspauling1/NaughtyPie/blob/master/src/App.jsx  . The trick which worked was to wrap the button within a typography element.

Comment: Ideally that should not be the case. You can try another thing, you can set the maxWidth of the button to fit the content in it. Updated the answer!